# How to undo the last commit in git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset, git-revert

By mistake, I did `git add .` and `git commit` in the `develop` branch. But luckily, I did not do `git push`.

So I wanted to revert it back to original state.

I tried `git reset --soft` and `git reset HEAD --hard` but looks like I have messed it up.

How do I fix this? I want to go back to original state and possibly keep the code changes.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

I think you haven't messed up yet. Try:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This will bring the dir to state before you've made the commit, `HEAD^` means the parent of the current commit (the one you don't want anymore), while keeping changes from it (unstaged).

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but this is the over simplistic answer that I want 90% of the time. Thank you

Comment: You, sir/ma'am, are a savior!

Comment: After you do this, if you want to completely remove the unstaged changes, you'll need to run the following:  git reset --hard HEAD

Comment: Don't know why this answer marked as correct. I get error thrown `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions,` Doesn't work

Comment: @Green same for me. I used this command instead to completely remove last commit: 
`git reset --hard HEAD~1`
[Found here](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit)

Comment: if `fatal: ambiguous argument` simply use `git reset -- HEAD^`

Comment: On windows, the caret is a special character for CMD (it's used to escape a character, similar to the backslash in Linux) so you better quote "HEAD^".

Comment: 95% of the time this works 100%... too bad I didn't find it a month ago! Simple, which is what I need.

Comment: Question - and if i have done add . commit and the pull , i believe that this might effect on other files too and not only on mine?

Answer (score 138):

Try simply to reset last commit using `--soft` flag

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

**Note** :

For Windows,  wrap the HEAD parts in quotes like `git reset --soft "HEAD~1"`

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

Comment: Try using git bash. If you're using Windows the console won't work for some reason, not sure why. Git bash does tho.

Comment: @Green Windows doesn't like `HEAD~1`, wrap it in quotes like `git reset --soft "HEAD~1"`